# Hibernate com banco

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate

Estou usando criando um programa que adiciona um informações num banco de dados através do hibernate, a quase uma hora atrás estava funcionando perfeitamente, mas agora quando executo o código gera esses erros.

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:84)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2791)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3361)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:478)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:198)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
>       at br.com.iesam.horario.utils.Teste.popularBanco(Teste.java:81)
>       at br.com.iesam.horario.utils.Teste.main(Teste.java:20)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`horarioprofessores`.`disciplinas`, CONSTRAINT `FKiica8mlykvmu920xf6ld3g66k` FOREIGN KEY (`idDisciplina`) REFERENCES `turmas` (`idTurma`))
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>       ... 23 more.

o código segue esse exemplo

```js
public class Teste {
    private static Session session;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 session = Conexao.getSession();// Add no banco de dados
 
 popularBanco();
 
 Conexao.close();
    }
  
  
  
  
   public static void popularBanco() {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
 try {
                 
//            professores.add(new Professores("João João"));
//            professores.add(new Professores("Maria Maria"));     
//            session.save(professores);
            
            // adicionar horarios
            Horarios hora[][][] = new Horarios[5][3][5];
            for (int dia = 0 ; dia < 5 ; dia++) {
                for (int turno = 0 ; turno < 3 ; turno++) {
                    for (int horario = 0 ; horario < 5 ; horario ++) {
                        hora[dia][turno][horario] = new Horarios(dia,turno,horario);
                        session.save(hora[dia][turno][horario]);
                    }
                }
            }

                        
             ProfessoresHorarios prof1 = new ProfessoresHorarios(AderbalMaia, hora[0][1][0], 2);
             session.save(prof1);
             ProfessoresHorarios prof2 = new ProfessoresHorarios(ElionaiSobrinho, hora[2][1][1], 3);
             session.save(prof2);
             ProfessoresHorarios prof3= new ProfessoresHorarios(ElionaiSobrinho, hora[1][0][0], 1);
             session.save(prof3);
             ProfessoresHorarios prof4 = new ProfessoresHorarios(ElionaiSobrinho, hora[4][1][1], 1);
             session.save(prof4);
      
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     tx.rollback();
 }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Você esta tentando mudar algum registro existente ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miguel pelo log de erro vc esta violando uma constraint, pelo visto uma chave estrangeira, veja

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(horarioprofessores.disciplinas, CONSTRAINT FKiica8mlykvmu920xf6ld3g66k FOREIGN KEY 
(idDisciplina) REFERENCES turmas (idTurma)) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

de uma olhada aqui **horarioprofessores.disciplinas** vc esta violando uma regra que vc criou no banco.